# Strange behavior in injecting EntityManager

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi

I observed some strange behavior regarding injecting EntityManager.

Following is stripped down version of working code:

**Bean.java**

```java
@RequestScoped
@Named
public class Bean {

    @Inject
    private Service service; // +getter

    // few variables + getters/setters

    public String getMessage() {
        return getService().message();
    }

}
```

**Service.java**

```java
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class Service {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager; // +getter

    public String message() {
        return "[" + getEntityManager() + "]";
    }

}
```

**cdi.xhtml**

```xhtml
<h:body>
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.message}" />
</h:body>
```

But I needed to do some processing, while creating ***Service***. So added following producer method, in factory class.

```java
    @Produces
    @QService
    public Service createService() {
        Service service;

        service = new Service();
        // Some processing
        return service;
    }
```

and added same qualifier ***QService*** at injection point in class ***Bean***.

```java
    @Inject
    @QService
    private Service service; // +getter
```

Now, EntityManager is **NOT** injected in class ***Service***, it remains null.

I'm not able to understand this behavior. Can someone explain this?

Comment: What's the output? Are you sure that the null object is the PersitenceContext and not the Service?

Comment: @perissf Output is **[null]** displayed in browser. Basically, that is the output of method **message()** of class **Service**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is this line:

```
service = new Service();
```

Since `Service` is an EJB it's lifecycle is managed by the container. You are allowed to call `new` but I guess you will not get an EJB but a pure java class.

Try to inject the Service EJB instead of creating a new instance.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely correct. I injected **Service** in factory class, and returned that instead of **new Service();**. And now it works as required. Wonder if the results will be similar if **Service** was **NOT** an EJB. Need to try that! Thanks a lot.

Comment: the trouble is **NOT** because of **Service** being an EJB. Same thing happens even if I take two POJOs in place of **Service**, and **EntityManager**. So, the conclusion is '***Injection works only if object is managed by container.***'. This is probably, as per spec, but not clear enough, for me. So, instead of using `service = new Service();`, needed to use `public Service createService(@New Service service)`.